# Designing butterworth filter with pole placement

Tags: filters, filter-design, butterworth

I am trying to design a Nth order continous time Butterworth filter in state space, with pole placement technique.

```
n = varargin{1}
Fc = this.fc 
wc = 2*pi*Fc;
T = 1/(2*pi*Fc);
%----------------Finding Poles--------------------------
 p = exp(1i*(pi*(1:2:n-1)/(2*n) + pi/2)); %n is the order of the filter
                 p = [p; conj(p)];
                 p = p(:);
                 if rem(n,2)==1   % n is odd
                     p = [p; -1];
                 end
%----------------Finding Filter co efficents---------------
                 if length(p)<= 2
                    a = conv([1,-p(1)],[1,-p(2)]);
                end
                if length(p) > 2
                    a = conv([1,-p(1)],[1,-p(2)]);
                    for i = 3: length(p)
                        a = conv(a,[1,-p(i)]);
                    end
                end
                a = real(a)
                a = fliplr(a);
%----------------- calculating the matricies%-----------------

            %--------------A matrix---------------
            N = length(a)-1;% order of the matrix
            last_row = (a(1:end-1))*(-1/a(end));% creating the last row

             last_row = (wc.^(N:-1:1)).*last_row;% creating the last row

            k = ones(1,N-1);
            this.x = diag(k,1) ; % diag(vector, k) produce a matrix filled with zero's and k'th off diagonal as vector, in this  case, 1's.
            this.x(end,:) = last_row;% adding the last_row

            %-------------desiging B matrix--------------
            this.y = zeros(N,1); % creates a coloumn matrix with zeros
            this.y(N,:) = 1/(a(end)*wc^n); % writes last elements as a

            %--------------- writing C matrix--------------
            this.z = zeros(1,N); %creates a row matrix
            this.z(1,1) = 1;

            %------------ writing the D matrix----------------

            this.u = [0];
```

I know the code is bit lengthy, but i have tried everything, but can't figure out where i am going wrong. Because I am not getting any error. The resultant output is just 0. The code is pretty simple, I find the poles, then the filter coefficients. with the filter coefficients. i design A,B;C,D Matrices. 
This is a continuous butterworth filter, Can anyone point the mistake i am doing?

edit1:
A low pass PT2 filter:
[image]

A low pass 2nd order butterworth filter:
[image]

Comment: Your code looks OK. How do you compute the output?

Comment: I discretize the filter, and apply it to my signal. I have another filter which works fine, i will show you the output. Maybe you can compare. Are you sure i compute A,B,C,D matrices correctly? I have a doubt about my A matrix

Comment: I took same configuration for both filter, same order, same Fc, same Ts.

Comment: So you used the same code to implement both filters using SS matrices? How did you obtain the matrices for the PT2 filter?

Comment: I did not use same code for implementation of both filter, i said the parameters used for both the plot is same, my another PT2  filter is general  PTn filter which is achieved by cascading of low pass PT1 filter. I have edited the code.

Comment: @MattL., i have edited with my general PTn filter code, would be glad if you pointed out the error in my butterworth Implementation. Because i have literally tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Everything was fine except for the denormalization step for arbitrary cut-off frequencies `wc`. I changed the following lines to obtain the correct state-space matrices (and to handle the case `n=1`):

```
...
if (n == 1)
    a = [1,1];
else
    p = ...
    ...
end

a = real(a);
a = a./(wc.^(n:-1:0))   % new!
a = fliplr(a);
...

% last_row = (wc.^(N:-1:1)).*last_row;    % removed!

if( n == 1)
    this.x = last_row;
else
    k = ones(1,N-1);
    this.x = diag(k,1) ;
    this.x(end,:) = last_row;
end

...

this.y(N,:) = 1/a(end);    % changed!

...
```

I used the function `ss2tf` to compute the polynomial coefficients from the state-space matrices computed above, and the coefficients were correct for different values of `wc`. This means that the matrices are correct. If the output signal is still different from what you expect, the problem must be in the filtering routine.

Comment: Thank you! Oh my god! But i have a problem when i choose 1st order, above 2nd order everything works  fine. but when i give 1st order i get this error. `Attempted to access p(2); index out of bounds because numel(p)=1.

Error in ltiFilter.PTn/test1 (line 29)
                    a = conv([1,-p(1)],[1,-p(2)]);` I kinda understand how this is happening, but not entirely sure. any idea? Again thank you!

Comment: i did some debugging, I think i will hard code the filter coeffcients if the order is 1. seems like a simple fix

Comment: Ok i thought i would hard code these values when the order is 1, A= [-1/wc];
                    B = [1];
                    C = [1];
                    D = [0]; I am clearly missing something, any idea?

Comment: @user5603723: I added some code for handling the case `n=1`. It's a quick hack but I think it should work.

Comment: I am not yet allowed to upvote, but accepted. Thank you!